# xUnit - mocked method for the async List returns null

Tags: xunit, nsubstitute

Here's the strange thing - when I run the Unit Test and I put the breakpoint on the line `return Unit.Value;`, then I see that the `someResult` value is null - but when I manually move the debugger's yellow arrow the the previous line again `var someResult = await _myRepository.DoSomething(cancellationToken);` then the `someResult` variable is not null and contains my object - why does that happen ?

Unit test snippet:

```
//Arrange
var myList = new List<MyTable> { new MyTable() };
var myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();
myRepository.DoSomething(Arg.Any<CancellationToken>()).Returns(myList);

var command = Substitute.For<MyCommand>();

//Act
var sut = new MyCommandHandler(myRepository);
await sut.Handle(command, Arg.Any<CancellationToken>());
```

I also tried:

```
myRepository.DoSomething(Arg.Any<CancellationToken>()).Returns(Task.FromResult(myList));
```

The tested class:

```
public class MyCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<MyCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public MyCommandHandler(IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(myRepository));
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(MyCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var someResult = await _myRepository.DoSomething(cancellationToken);

        ...
        return Unit.Value;
    }
}

public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyRepository(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<MyTable>> DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await _context.MyTable
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(...)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Tony, what test framework are you using? NUnit? xUnit? something else? And is your test async? Bit more code of the test itself may help. With it being populated interactively feels like that's not the case.

Comment: hi @rgvlee I'm using xUnit and I've edited my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `Arg.Any<CancellationToken>()` matcher in your `Handle` invocation is the problem.

Changing

```
await sut.Handle(command, Arg.Any<CancellationToken>());
```

to

```
await sut.Handle(command, default);
```

got the test working. The matchers are for configuring the substitute and checking the received invocations, not for the actual invocation itself.

A working example can be found [here](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question61426094). I didn't have enough to go on to replicate `Unit` and it's usage but was able to observe and resolve the same problem you were having without it.

Comment: This answer is correct. See [How not to use arg matchers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/argument-matchers/#how-not-to-use-argument-matchers) for an explanation. Adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to tests projects will detect issues like this.

Comment: ah, so here's the problem - I didn't notice it. Thank you !